# $_FILES empty when sending Image with POST

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, rest

I want to do pretty simple thing. Send image via HTTP to my Php Backend. However the $_FILES array remains empty.

My FrontEnd is looking like this:

```
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', this.newPhoto);
await fetch('http://localhost:8080/addArticle', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
        },
        body: formData,
      })
        .then((response) => console.log(response))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

My Payload in Network Tab on Dev Tools is looking like this: First time sending Images, so not really sure whether it looks correctly.

And on server side just simply try to see this files now via

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrN63.png
What am i missing?

In HTML it looks like this. Iam usinng Vuetify libarry for Vue:

```
<v-file-input v-model="newPhoto" show-size accept="image/*" label="Photo"></v-file-input>
```

Console log of example photo:
i.stack.imgur.com/mpy9d.png

Comment: It would probably be useful to see the HTML Form and the code that loads `formData`

Comment: I added it as you wish